# SAML VALIDATION

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I have a controller which takes the base64 encoded SAML response as the body,
I want to check whether my SAML response has been tampered with.
I have public key which i got from the metadata file, is this the right way to Extract the public key from the metadata and convert it to X509Certificate ??
also how do i validate the signature and the public key ??
any blog or anything related would be much appreciated.
I'm using openSAML v2.5.1-1

```
@PostMapping("/saml")
    public void samlValidation(@RequestBody String samlBody) throws Exception{

        // Decode the SAML response and parse the assertion
        Response response = (Response) unmarshall(samlBody);

        // Extract the signature from the response
        Signature signature = response.getSignature();

        // Extract the public key from the metadata and convert it to X509Certificate
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = SecurityHelper.buildJavaX509Cert(publicKey);


    }
```